# Is there an error in the solution for this exercise?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I have this exercise:

> H is a complex hilbert space. And T is a compact operator on H. Show
>   that if H is not separable, then 0 is an eigenvalue of T.
>
> Hint: Use lemma 1, and theorem 2.

The lemma it refers to is this:

Lemma 1:

> Let Y be a closed linear subspace of a Hilbert space H. Show that if
>   $Y\ne H$, then $Y^\perp\ne\{0\}$.

The theorem it refers to is this:

Theorem 2:

> Let X and Y be normed spaces and let T be a linear operator($T\in
> L(X,Y)$). Then
>
> if T is compact then $\text{Im } T$ and $\overline{\text{Im T}}$ are
>   seperable.

The solution is this:

> Since H is not seperable it follows from Theorem 2 that
>   $\overline{\text{Im T}}\ne H$, so Ker T =$\overline{\text{Im
>  T}}^\perp\ne\{0\}$(see Lemma 1). Thus there exists $e \ne0$ such that $Te=0$,
>   that is, e is an eigenvector of T, with eigenvalue 0.

But they use that Ker T =$\overline{\text{Im T}}^\perp$. How do they get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That result quoted in the solution is not quite true: what is true is that $\text{Ker } T = (\text{Im } T^*)^{\perp}$.  It doesn't matter, though, since $T$ being compact implies that its Hilbert space adjoint $T^*$ is compact as well.  Hence, by Theorem 2, $(\text{Im } T^*)^{\perp} \neq \{0\}$, so that there is an $e \neq 0$ in $H$ so that $Te=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I just have one question. I have seen that Ker T=$\text{(Im T*)}^\perp$, but how do you get it with a closure?

Comment: Ah, yes that's right, sorry about that.  I edited my answer to omit the closures.

Comment: No, I think your answer as it was was correct, because in order to use Lemma 1, you need it to be closed. So I think the first version was correct, but there is some justification as to why it works with closures aswell.

Comment: Yes that's right.  Either way, it still works.